# Exporting a MySQL table into a CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL table which has to be taken out as a CSV file. The query I used is

```
SELECT "ID","NAME","SALARY","SAL1","SAL2","SAL3","SAL4","SAL5","SAL6","SAL7","SAL8","SAL9","SAL10","SAL11","SAL12","SAL13","SAL14","SAL15","SAL16","SAL17","SAL18","SAL19","SAL20","SAL21","SAL22","SAL23","SAL24","SAL25","SAL26"
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM addstock25
INTO OUTFILE "E:\\JOSE DATA\\addstock7.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This query works, but what if I have 200 column names?
Is there a way to do it without manually typing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL dump into CSV text files with column names at the top?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589891/mysql-dump-into-csv-text-files-with-column-names-at-the-top)

Comment: mysqldump with --tab should be the easy way here with no additional scripting requirements. I wrote [3 ways to convert MySQL to CSV](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/export-mysql-database-table-to-csv-delimited-excel-file) in detail.

Answer (score 73):

This command almost gives you what you want, and it even works with a remote server. The only caveat is that it generates a TSV file (fields are separated by a tab).

```
mysql mydb -e "select * from mytable" -B > mytable.tsv
```

But you could convert it to CSV using sed, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040816/dump-all-tables-in-csv-format-using-mysqldump/25427665#25427665):

```
mysql mydb -e "select * from mytable" -B | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > mytable.csv
```

Comment: Can i use where clause?

Comment: @Lnux yes you can use a where clause to narrow down the search, everything in the first quoted area with the select, is a normal database query.

Comment: mysql -u root -p mydb -e "select * from mytable" -B | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > mytable.csv - This worked fine for me, thank you

Comment: Can you help me modify this to use multiple tables in a bash script to append to the output file?

Comment: can we import this exported tsv ?

Answer (score 5):

```
DESCRIBE addstock25;
```

Strip the first column and the first three entries of that column (it depends on your usage). You will get the list of fields in addstock25.

This will bring only field names using virtual tables derived in core... called information schema.

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='foo';
```

Let’s say the name of this query would be sq_fieldnamelist.

So, the above table has one column and it has the field names of the "foo" table.

If directly writing like

```
SELECT (sq_fieldnamelist)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM addstock25
INTO OUTFILE "E:\\JOSE DATA\\addstock7.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n
```

MySQL will give an error. "subquery returns multiple rows"

We must edit sq_fieldnamelist to concatenate all entries back to back, separated with commas.

```
Select GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM
(SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='ffd_companies'
LIMIT 3,100
) AS fafa
GROUP BY 'COLUMN_NAME' // This group by is just to make group concatenation work
```

Let's say this is sq_fieldnamelist2.

If we edit sq_fieldnamelist like this, it will return only one value which is all field names separated with commas. So now we can put this subquery in your select statement to acquire the needed fields.

```
SELECT (sq_fieldnamelist2)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM addstock25
INTO OUTFILE "E:\\JOSE DATA\\addstock7.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n
```

You need to edit LIMIT 3,100 in sq_fieldnamelist2 for you own purpose.

Let's say your table is like fil1, fil2...filN, sal1, sal2, sal3...., salI. To see the only salary fields, you should use `LIMIT N, x > I+N`. If you want to see all, use `LIMIT 0, x > N+I`.

Comment: I could'nt understand what you are explaining .... What i want is the csv file exported from MySQL with column names in first line .

Comment: giving u a way to copy col names - a little automatic

Comment: i think you want something like this

Answer (score 4):

I'm not seeing why you can't do

```
SELECT *
FROM addstock25
INTO OUTFILE "E:\\JOSE DATA\\addstock7.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: If i do so, I dont get the column names... i have 200 columns so how can i export it with column names ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("'",COLUMN_NAME,"'")
 FROM
(SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourdatabasename'
and `TABLE_NAME`='ffd_companies'
) AS colnames
GROUP BY 'COLUMN_NAME'
into @sql;

SET @sql = concat ("SELECT", @sql, " from dual
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM addstock25
INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\JOSE DATA\\addstock7.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '", '"',"'
)"
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Note that I added the `WHERE` clause `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourdatabasename'.

Comment: Its giving out an error message.... I changed the database name .... Any other changes to be made ?

Comment: Please tray this and tel me if its working.

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT("'", COLUMN_NAME, "'")
FROM(
  SELECT
    `COLUMN_NAME`
  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourdatabase'
  AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'ffd_companies') AS colnames
GROUP BY 'COLUMN_NAME' INTO @sql;

SET @sql = concat ("SELECT", @sql, " from dual 
  union all(
    SELECT * from ffd_companies
    
    )"
  );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Answer (score 0):

Can use 'Table Data Export Wizard' and from there can copy the select SQL;