# How to insert 1,10,000 records from mysql to excel sheet using ruby script

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have around 1,10,000 records in my database which I want to export to excel sheet. I am able to insert 1,000 records without any issue using "spreadsheet" gem. But after 1,000 real deal start. From 1,000 to 2,000 records, it's very slow insertion with 100% CPU utilization. After 2,000 whole system is crashing.

Create excel sheet with 1,000 records in one excel sheet and then merging excel-sheets is not preferred.

```
    Environment: 
    Linux-Ubuntu 14.04 OS, 
    Ram: 1GB, 
    Ruby Version: ruby 2.3.1p112
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use any gems, nor export to the excel format. Produce a [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

While it’s a plain text format, excel reads it without any glitch.

---

Also, MySQL has an ability to [export to CSV itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783202/exporting-mysql-table-into-a-csv-file#28897323).

Comment: How to use 
  mysql mydb -e "select * from mytable" -B | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > mytable.csv   
in the ruby script ?

Comment: Why would you want to use shell command from a ruby script? Just run it from shell, or use the approach with CSV from ruby.

Comment: First of all thanks a ton for taking out time and replying back, really appreciate your help. 

Well, I am working on a ruby-script which fetches data which is huge and that data has to be inserted in excel sheet. So is the reason I am trying to use this command in ruby-script, which I am failing to do. Look for some solution around.