# Is there a way to enclose fields in a Mysql set within a character?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to unload data from Mysql and know of the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` but that requires extra permissions for my user. While I wait for those perms, I was wondering if there's a setting I can add to a general `select` clause to enclose fields within a character like a double quotation `"`. I figure this would work, but it requires a lot of editing and I have hundreds of fields to apply this to...

```
SELECT
 concat('"' , field1, '"'),
 concat('"' , field2, '"')
from 
 mytable
```

Comment: maybe export to csv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783202/exporting-mysql-table-into-a-csv-file

Comment: Just pop your list of fields into excel and then do `="concat('" & char(34) & "' , " & A1 & ", '" & char(34) & "'),"` and copy the formula down, then copy paste the list into your sql client.