# How to save MSSQL query output to .txt or .json file?

Tags: json, sql-server

How to save output of a Select query to a .json file or .txt file?using MSSQL Server

> Table A contains id,name,address

I tried the query below,

```
SELECT * from A INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt';
```

but it produced an Error,

```
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
```

How do i resolve the error?. Even if it's only possible to store the data in a .txt file, it will be okay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262924/how-to-export-dump-a-mysql-table-into-a-text-file-including-the-field-names-a

Comment: I think that this question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253704/how-to-save-mysql-query-output-to-excel-or-txt-file

Comment: I try it produce error @SureshKamrushi

Comment: i require to create .json file if not possible then .txt file is okay @LePanz

Comment: @R.Gopalakrishnan check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275272/2469308  - if it works for you, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As per the original question, which was tagged as MySQL:** Your syntax is wrong. As per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html), `FROM` clause comes after `INTO OUTFILE` clause. Following should work **in MySQL**:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt'
FROM A
```

In order to get Comma-separated values in the text file, you can do the following instead (**in MySQL**):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM A;
```

**For MS SQL Server**: There is no `INSERT INTO OUTFILE` clause available. Instead, a different solution is proposed using SQL Server Management Studio at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354143/2469308

Comment: SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '/tmp/orders.txt'.
  Incorrect syntax near '/tmp/orders.txt'.
  Incorrect syntax near '/tmp/orders.txt'.

Comment: i try it@Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: I try both ways Same Error will be come.@MadhurBhaiya

Comment: @R.Gopalakrishnan What is your Mysql version ? are you sure that you are on mysql ?

Comment: Based on your error, I think you are on MS SQL Server , not Mysql

Comment: Yes!!@Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server@Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: @R.Gopalakrishnan for MS SQL Server, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354143/2469308

There is no SELECT INTO OUTFILE in MS Sql server

Comment: Thanks!!@Madhur Bhaiya